# need to customize the jQuery Nested Accordion Menu script?

Tags: jquery, css

### This is the script i need to be customized,

Please review the link.

[jQuery Nested Accordion Menu](http://jordanrodriguez.com/jquery-nested-accordion-menu/#comment-1088)

i need to modify some customization in this script by default the menus will be display with out color when we select the particular menu header it will be displayed in some different color.

How can i implement this option in this script.
for ex:
now the header menu displayed in blue color, but i need by default the menu will be displayed in with out color having only outer border. if we select the main header it will be displayed with some color. expecting your reply.

Thanks

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem. And add code to your question.

Comment: you just gone through the mentioned link in that script by default the menu displayed in blue color. by i want to set the color for menu when its opened? got my point?

Comment: by default it will not displayed any colors for the menu tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to edit its css

```
#nestedAccordion h2{
background-color: #4B8CFF;
}
```

remove the bg color from here. then your menu will not have blue background.

if you need when someone select the menu

```
$("#nestedAccordion h2").click(function() {
$(this).css('background-color', '#4B8CFF');


});
```